# How could I rewrite this without using arrow functions?

Tags: ecmascript-6, arrow-functions, ecmascript-next

I don't understand how to untangle the double arrow binding. My linter does not like this ES7+ magic.

```
    export default class Login extends Component {
     handleChange = (fieldName) => (evt) => {
        this.setState({
          [fieldName]: evt.target.value,
          errors: {...this.state.errors, [fieldName]: null}
        })
      }
  }
```

Comment: You should fix your linter then - what is the warning message? Btw, the arrow functions are ES6, only the object spread is beyond ES7.

Comment: I would like to understand how to untangle this regardless of my linter. I know arrows are ES6 but initialising a method without binding it inside a react class is most definitely ES7+ magic. The warning is `Unexpected token = (null)`. I'm using standardjs.

Comment: That also looks like probably the body of a class property. The ES6 way would be to have that inside your constructor, or to make it a method and bind it separately.

Comment: There's no sign that it is a method. How should we guess?

Comment: The added context of the class is irrelevant in this case. The question is only about rewriting the arrows with function statements. I didn't add it because I thought it would be misleading. @estus Would you like me to wrap the method in a class?

Comment: @JoshPittman Yes, definitely, what you've shown is nothing but a simple assignment. If the class field is what your linter does have problems with, you need to specify that.

Comment: @Bergi I'm just asking if someone can help me rewrite the simple assignment without arrow functions.

Comment: *"The added context of the class is irrelevant in this case."* Not at all, it's exactly what the problem is. Class fields are experimental, arrow functions are not.

Comment: Thank you @FelixKling. I understand now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the arrow functions, `Unexpected token =` means that your linter doesn't like [class fields](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-public-fields). Just move the whole thing inside the constructor:

```
export default class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.handleChange = (fieldName) => (evt) => {
      this.setState({
        [fieldName]: evt.target.value,
        errors: {...this.state.errors, [fieldName]: null}
      });
    };
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you so much.